# How to create a "rubber rectangle selection" in the bing maps

Tags: wpf, bing-maps

I am using Bing maps WPF control to render maps. My requirement is allow user to create a rectangle and based on the co-ordinates of the rectangle drawn I need to fetch the lat, long information.

I achieved by the following way.

```
 private MapPolygon boundingRectangle;
```

My **mouse_leftButtonDown** code looks like

```
 Point point = e.GetPosition(this);
 this.mouseCordinates = new PointCollection();
 this.mouseCordinates.Add(point);
```

**mouse_leftButtonUp** code looks like

```
var point = e.GetPosition(this);

this.mouseCordinates.Add(point);

var pt1 = this.mouseCordinates[0];
var pt3 = this.mouseCordinates[1];
var pt2 = new System.Windows.Point(pt3.X, pt1.Y);
var pt4 = new System.Windows.Point(pt1.X, pt3.Y);

var loc1 = this.ViewportPointToLocation(pt1);
var loc2 = this.ViewportPointToLocation(pt2);
var loc3 = this.ViewportPointToLocation(pt3);
var loc4 = this.ViewportPointToLocation(pt4);

this.Children.Remove(this.boundingRectangle);

this.boundingRectangle = new MapPolygon
{
    Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Chocolate),
    StrokeThickness = 2,
    Locations = new LocationCollection()
    {
        loc1,
        loc2,
        loc3,
        loc4
    }
};

this.BoundingBoxCoordinates = this.boundingRectangle.Locations;
this.Children.Add(this.boundingRectangle);
```

So on mouse up I got a shape which user drawn. But while drawing (I mean while dragging the mouse since no mouse movement event is handled) user is not able to see anything on the map. Only on the mouse up user can see the shape they drawn because the layer children is added after mouse up.

What I want is "rubber selection" rectangle meaning while drawing the shape using mouse drag user should see the shape. It should be lively.

As I am new to WPF and map I am still struggling to figure this out.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done a lot of work with the Bing Maps and the WPF control. I've put together a code sample that shows how to draw rectangles on the map using both the mouse and touch. The sample is a bit too long for a forum post. I've uploaded it to MSDN here: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Draw-Rectangles-on-Bing-ce083d0e